# Getting a traceback while inheriting from imported files

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance

@first.py

```
class first():

   def fun1():
       print 'first one'
```

@second.py

```
class second():

    def fun2():
        print 'second one'
```

@third.py

```
import first

import second

class third (first, second):

    def fun3():
        f= first()
        s= second()
        f.fun1()
        s.fun2()
        print 'third one'
```

on running the third.py, i'm getting a traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\third.py", line 4, in <module>
    class third (first, second):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: You named your class the same thing as your module, so the proper way to instantiate an object here would be `f = first.first()` and `s = second.second()` Same thing with your class inheritence `class third(first.first, second.second)` That's probably a good hint to use some useful, meaningful names for both the modules and classes respectively

Comment: Python is not Java; when you import a module you get a reference to the module itself, not the class it contains. (Especially as modules can contain multiple classes.)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you import file but didn't import class

@first.py

```
class First(object):

   def fun1(self):
       print 'first one'
```

---

@second.py

```
class Second(object):

    def fun2(self):
        print 'second one'
```

---

@third.py

```
import first

import second

class Third(object):

    def fun3(self):
        f= first.First()
        s= second.Second()
        f.fun1()
        s.fun2()
        print 'third one'


Third().fun3()
```

---

```
#output:
first one
second one
third one
```

---

Also another way you can call first and second class from file is given below:

@third.py

```
from first import First
from second import Second

class Third(object):
    def fun3(self):
        f= First()
        s= Second()
        f.fun1()
        s.fun2()
        print 'third one'


Third().fun3()
```